# Photoshop: making the outer glow colour dependent on edge colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Looking to make a lighting effect with a scatter brush that makes circles of different colours on the same layer (using scatter and colour dynamics). I'd like to add the outer glow effect on this layer, however I can only define a single colour for it, thereby making each scattered circle have the same colour glow that looks off.

Is there a way to make the outer glow effect take the colour of the edge it is projected off? Or another way to a diffuse glow, around each scattered circle, that takes the colour of the circle it emanates from?

Comment: Duplicate the layer and then blur the duplicate maybe?

Comment: That is a really good idea, hadn't thought of that. Let me try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the Outer Glow layer effect on itself **cannot** achieve that, period.

An alternative that has already been mentioned by Scott is duplicate the layer then blur. The downside of this is that you'd have to repeat that everytime you changed your artwork.

But you can use **Smart Filters** to do it dynamically. Select the layer you want to make glow, convert it to Smart Object, then duplicate it and apply the blur filter as you would normally. But this time, if you double click either of them, you'll edit it as a whole new document. Whenever you change it, both copies will update.

[image: Layer with smart filter]